# socket.io 'connect' or 'reconnect' event not fired after reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

i have a problem with using Socket.io.

code is simple:

```
var socket = null;
var socketInit = false;    //if it is true, use reconnect

...
function connect() {
    if(!socketInit) {
        socket = io();
        socketInit = true;

        //attach event handlers
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connect fired!');
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('disconnect fired!');
        });
        socket.on('reconnect', function() {
            console.log('reconnect fired!');
        });
    }
    else {
        socket.io.connect();
    }
}

...
function disconnect() {
    socket.disconnect();
}
```

as you can see, there are two functions that connect or disconnect socket. and in connect function, it attachs 'connect', 'disconnect', 'reconnect' handlers to the socket.

first i called connect function, it works well. server side is also working well. and i called disconnect function, works well too so as the server.

but i called connect function again, that means "socketInit" variable is true, so connect function tries:

```
socket.io.connect();
```

i checked the server and client console both, and looks like it has connected, but the problem is the events are not fired!

server side 'connection' event was fired on reconnection but client side 'connect' or 'reconnect' event wasn't fired. i tried to figure out what is going on, but still i don't get it. i checked web console and server console many times, and the connection itself is working fine, but the problem is events are not working!

if someone know the way, it will be very appreciated to help me. thanks ;)

p.s. i tried to add 'reconnected', 'reconnection', 'reconnect_error' event handlers, but neither not works.

Comment: I am not sure that you can do it like that. Who is connecting to this socket? If it's a socket.io client, then only the client can reconnect.

Comment: xbirkett// thanks for comment. those are client side code. i just want to do is client can connect/disconnect/reconnect anytime he wants. do you have better suggestion about this? it will be very thanks-full gimme a better way ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Socket.io 1.0, try using the io manager on the socket to handle manual disconnection and reconnection.

```
var socket = null;
var socketInit = false;

function connect() {
    if(!socketInit) {
        socket = io();
        socketInit = true;

        //attach event handlers
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connect fired!');
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('disconnect fired!');
        });
        socket.on('reconnect', function() {
            console.log('reconnect fired!');
        });
    }
    else {
        socket.io.reconnect();
    }
}


function disconnect() {
    socket.io.disconnect();
}
```

The reconnecting_attempt, reconnecting, reconnected and connected events on the socket should all be emitted afterwards.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore with socket.io, because now disconnect sets `skipReconnecting=true` so calling `.reconnect()` does nothing, while calling `connect()` works to reconnect socket but doesn't fire the events!

Comment: Seems that, instead, we have the "open" and "close" events but the packets to connect and disconnect never arrive?

Answer (score 2):

I am using socket.io 2.1.1, and here is all the event sequence that when socket.io handle reconnect after disconnected:

Just do `socketClient.on(eventName, callBackFunc);`

[image]